# Confirm selection of a single file?

Tags: forms, web-app

In our application, user has the ability to import projects from a CSV file. It is done using modal dialog in which there is a description of the import, link to an example file and a clickable dropzone in which the user can either drop the csv file or select a file by clicking.

The only action that can be done in this dialog is selecting the file. The user cannot cancel or revert the import during upload nor after it completes.

A) **Should the import start right after the user selects the file or**

B) **should the user confirm the file selection by clicking a confirm button?**

[image: no confirm flow] [image]

Comment: How easy is it to undo the import if they choose the wrong file? This should IMHO be your ultimate metric for deciding whether to take confirmation steps away; make it trivial to back out what the user just did

Comment: I'd say it is difficult. But my point of view is that the user will not check the selected file and they click the button immediately. So the optimal solution would be displaying the changes before the user confirms the change like in @IlmariKaronen's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My intuition here is to show the file name (like in your example) and give the user a chance to confirm that it is the file they want to import. Giving the user (a sense of) control is a basic principle of user experience. I would expect that it will surprise users when the import starts immediately when they select a file. There is no indication it does, and even if there is one it can easily be overlooked or ignored.

> “the design projects all the information needed to create a good conceptual model of the system, leading to an understanding and a feeling of control”

<sub>Freely taken from https://uxdesign.cc/ux-psychology-principles-seven-fundamental-design-principles-39c420a05f84</sub>

The choice for the immediate import can only be justified if all of the following are true:

- The process of the import is a matter of milliseconds, not seconds
- The impact of importing the wrong file is negligible
- An import can be undone/reverted with ease

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the second option and display the filename as it allows the user a chance to check they've selected the correct file. Although it's an extra click, it is a common pattern that is used elsewhere and is likely to fit with their expectations.

Ideally it will also allow the user to replace the selected file by selecting a different file, just in case they selected the wrong one.

You could potentially also show any error messages on file selection (e.g. if the file is too large or the wrong format, before they click 'import'.

Answer (score 3):

If at all possible, I would suggest not only going with option B, but also showing some kind of a **preview of the file contents** in the confirmation dialog.

For a CSV file, such a preview could, in its most basic form, simply display the first few columns and rows of the file contents in a table.  I would suggest making the preview area scrollable, so that the user can, *if they want*, choose to look deeper into the file to confirm that it contains the data they want.  Of course, if you can present the data in a more processed form (i.e. as something closer to what the user would see after completing the import), that could be even better.

In a modern web app, you should be able to implement such a preview entirely on the client side using the [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/), thereby avoiding any data transfer delays.

FWIW, [like jazZRo](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/135463), I would only suggest going with option A *if* the import process is quick and can be safely and easily undone.  In that case, the import itself can effectively act as the preview, with the undo feature serving the same function as the "cancel" button in your option B.

In fact, you could even consider a hybrid approach, where you perform a "provisional" import (think something like a commit to a feature branch in Git), show the results *only* to the user, and then give the user a choice to either **accept** or **reject** the imported data.  Accepting the data would then permanently commit it to the system, make it accessible to other users, etc.  Of course, that's only practical if the data storage model in your app is designed in such a way that it can support such alternative or provisional data.

Comment: Yes, that would be the optimal solution. But IRL one does not always have all the resources (development capacity) for optimal solutions in a non-crucial part of applications.